# append wordpress user meta value to url in main wordpress menu

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm trying to append a custom user table meta value from my user table to the url of one of my main menu links, so the page will filter alumni by the user's grad year. I've tested the filter below, and it successfully appends to the URL, but I don't know how to change the "2023" part dynamically. I think I have to set a variable with the meta value, but just not sure how to code that piece. Also, do I need the "is_admin" piece? The alumni pages require a login, so I think I can remove that bit, yeah?

The meta table is wp_tmjbygkxf5_usermeta and the key I need to grab is: "graduation_years"

But again, just not sure how to update the code below to append the right value to the URL.  Thank you for ideas!

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items','nav_items', 11, 3 );

function nav_items( $items, $menu, $args ) 
{
    if( is_admin() )
        return $items;

    foreach( $items as $item ) 
    {       
        if( 'Find Old Friends!' == $item->post_title)
            
            $item->url .= '?filter_graduation_years_94217=2023'

    }
    return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep the "is_admin" to avoid this custom code to be executed when you view the menù from your backend.
About the real code i think all you need to do (if you are interested in the current logged in user metadata) is to change your code to this:

```
if (!empty($current_user_id = get_current_user_id())){
    $graduation_year = get_user_meta($current_user_id,'graduation_years',true);
    $item->url .= '?filter_graduation_years_94217='.$graduation_year;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but can you show how to put it all together?  Sorry... total php newbie!

Comment: Just use the code u've pasted, only edit the $item->url with my code, that should be enough